# Auth filter not working in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm building an API in Laravel to learn how to do such a thing. I'm following a Laracasts course to do this, but I can't get `$this->beforeFilter('auth.basic');` to work. This is my controller:

```
class LessonsController extends ApiController {

    protected $lessonstranformer;   

    function __construct(LessonTransformer $lessonTransformer)
    {

        $this->LessonTransformer = $lessonTransformer;

        $this->beforeFilter('auth.basic');

    }

    public function index() 
    {

        $lessons = Lessons::all();

        return $this->respond([

            'data' => $this->LessonTransformer->transformCollection($lessons->all())

        ]);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably one thing can cause the problem and that is:

```
$this->LessonTransformer = $lessonTransformer;
```

Should be:

```
$this->lessonTransformer = $lessonTransformer;
```

Because you have  `protected $lessonstranformer` not `protected $Lessonstranformer`. Also make sure that, your `ApiController` extends the `Controller` or `BaseController` which may extended the `Controller`.